# Creating multiple function onEdit(e) to work in one script

Tags: google-apps-script

My script below works as an independent script - It will add a date and a time in a cell/column opposite the trigger cell/ column. I.e. Any cell in Column A stating TRUE will have in its adjacent Column B cell stating the exact date & time, at any moment the cell in Column A is deemed to be TRUE. The script keeps this as as one single change. If I were to delete TRUE or change it to any other text, the data in column B would remain the same, until I write TRUE again - This will force the cell(s) in Column B to overwrite the previous date/time with the latest date/time the moment the new "TRUE" statement was issued in Column A.

Now, I would like to add another onEdit function where it works on Sheet 2, but the column reference numbers are not 1 (as you will see below, all numbers are 1, whether positive or negative), but will be 2. I do not know how to get the two separate functions to work as when I list them separately, with an identical script structure, only the last script in the sequence works, and the first one does not.

I hope I have made this clear enough; I am not a coder by any means, and I have done my best with tutorials, forums, etc before posting this question. I can learn better by reverse-engineering someone else's work rather than being given the building blocks and told to create something, but I appreciate any education on this so I can learn for the future.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
 if(col == 1) { //number of column(s) where you have a data
  var adjacentCell = aCell.offset(-1,-1);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
   "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
}}

function onEdit(e){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //change to be your sheet name so the script only triggers on that sheet
 if( ss.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  if(e.value != "TRUE") return;
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart+1).setValue(new 
  Date());
 }
}
```

Comment: Every function must have a unique name.

Comment: As Kai implies, break these out into their own functions. Then use the onEdit function as your entry point, set up a condition, and call the appropriate function based on the condition.

Comment: So Cooper, is the onEdit (e) the name of the function which has no relevance on the e.source or e.value in the script? I thought onEdit (e) is the root function or command which the function then undertakes. Again, sorry, I am not a coder, and as much as it is dangerous to use code you do not understand, I do not have a choice, so I must make it work as intended, even if it's not this code to do the job.

Comment: Clark Lind - Thanks for your comment. Trying to use Cooper's solution below works exactly as the script I posted (albeit more eloquently and in less lines!) - but I try to replicate this for Sheet 2 and run into the same issue. I understand I'm not giving a unique name to the function if I just copy and paste the script twice and change the sheet reference from 1 to 2, but what is the solution to this as whatever that is will probably solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have specified sufficient conditions for this to work correctly but this is what you have so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' &&  e.range.columnStart == 1) {
    e.range.offset(-1,-1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
  }
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

I imagine you will need further debugging to get this to work.

Comment: Cooper, thanks for this code. I took it and modified it, and it did work, in part, how my previous script worked. I was able to combine this with Sheet 2 in a repetitive constuct, ie. I replicated your script lines after const sh = e.range.getSheet(); for Sheet 2's requirements, which worked. But I then went onto a random sheet and wrote TRUE, which then caused the adjacent cell to populate with the date/time. I can't have this run anywhere other than the columns specified in the script, and it can't run anywhere other than Sheet 1.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to add `sh.getName() == 'Sheet1'` to both if's

Comment: I just tried to replicate what you had in your functions but I don't have access to your spreadsheets and I can't debug it so sorry if it didn't work perfectly but I said I thought it would need some debugging so my assumption is that you can fix it.  I don't care about points anymore

Comment: Ah, sorry. I can't give access. It's a simple, 3 sheet workbook, with TRUE in column A across sheet 1 and 2. And then TRUE in column N in sheet 3 (then the date script appears in the adjacent column). So the issue is when I try to use the same script, but alter it slightly because TRUE happens in sheet 3 in a different column than 1 and 2, so it can't be a direct replica. Additionally, you don't want the script to run on sheets other than 1, 2 or 3 which I think your script does from testing. Thanks for helping anyway, I'll keep trying. What do you mean about points?

Comment: Well many users think that the volunteers here will do anything for points.  It my case I'm way past caring about points.  If I can help you great, but if I can't I'm not going to jump through hoops to get a  few measly points.  I'm here to learn and I can write onedit functions very well for myself but sometimes they take considerable debugging and that means digging into the problem and figuring it out on your own.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining the points bit. I also didn't really know this was done by volunteers in a way - call me ignorant! Debugging is always harder I find rather than constructing but I'm also trying to learn. I think your script does exactly what it's meant to do, and what was asked for so I've got no problem that my issue is partly solved. So thank you anyway. The only thing I don't understand properly (but I think your first comment is the answer) is how I could run two identical scripts, doing the same thing, but referencing two separate sheet names, as two separate scripts?

Comment: I think my last edit shows how you can use to separate sheets.  Keep in mind that all the functions in a project have access to all of the sheets.